# Unexpected implicit cast to Button: layout tag was TextView

Tags: java, android

I cannot get it I have tried somethings like appcompat but not worked. Cannot figure out how to solve it.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    private Button button;
    private TextView textView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        button = findViewById(R.id.showName);  ---> Here it is giving the problem.
        textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);
        textView.setText("Hello from Java!!");
    }
}
```

Comment: upload your xml

Comment: Please post your xml, then I can figure out your bug.

Comment: Since you figured it out, and there is not enough information to answer the question, please consider deleting your question.  Or, [edit] your question to include the information, then post your answer.  Thanks.

Comment: Yeah Thanks i got it.It was textView. I have now converted it to Button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to showName is TextView, not Button, but I'm not sure.
Please check xml and change TextView to Button.

Please upload your xml.

Comment: Yeah Thanks i got it. It was textView first but i have converted it to Button.

Answer (score 0):

First the Button was TextView that's why it was giving Unexpected implicit cast to Button.
Then after changing it to Button it worked fine.

Then-->

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/showName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Show Name"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Now-->

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/showName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Show Name"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

After this it is running fine.